# TextView content aligning to left

Tags: android, textview, alignment

I've got simple recycler_view_item where I've got text view that should show some amount (image on the left)
recycler_view_item TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:text="500"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/debtors_item_leftamount"
    android:textSize="@dimen/debtors_left_amount_size"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/debtors_item_arrow"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"/>
```

Does anybody know how to make it was align to left like on the right image?

I've tried

```
android:textAlignment="textStart"
android:textAlignment="viewStart"
android:gravity=start, left, even top or any other
```

Nothing has been changed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:gravity="left"
```

Comment: I can't use match_parent because parent of this TextView is whole recyclerView item and there are other elements

Comment: But you gave me indirect advice. I have used raw size of width(50for example) and then set textAlignment to textStart and it work properly!

Answer (score 0):

How about this ??

You wrap the contents of the recycler view in linear layout as follows ::

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_parent"
  android:weightSum="10"
  android:gravity="center">

  //use the weight to define the layout_width="0" and layout_weight of the child elements 
  //define weight as required as matching your requirements.

  //example below for Image View you are using
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:gravity="center">

</LinearLayout>
```

This will give you fixed responsive width and height from device perspective as well. You will be able to use the gravity to define the position of the element as well.